# How to manage and edit metadata of an audio file in Java

Tags: java, audio, metadata, aac

Greetings!!
I've been searching a lot about how to read the metadata of .aac file on Java, but still hasn't succeeded in finding somethong useful. I'm new in programming and I'm doing this as an assignment. The most of info I found was this:

http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html

But I can't make a simple program work because the import shown there doesn't exist!! I believe that's for an older JDK but the site says it's updated.

I don't where to start, beginning from which imports I should make, to knowing where metadata may be located in an .acc file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

[Oreilly](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/QuickTime_for_Java%3a_A_Developer%27s_Notebook/Audio_Media#Reading_Information_from_iTunes_AAC_Files) provides some info about AAC Files specifically created by iTunes, however it does give a fairly good code sample in Java of how to read metadata information.

I am assuming the question is asking more of the specifications of AAC rather than a third party library which can handle metadata creation the way I read it.